# Missing WSMan provider on PowerShell Linux (to use remoting)

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

I'm trying to remote PowerShell from Linux to a Windows Nano Server on Azure.

There's a part in the instructions where I add the IP of the remote server to local computer's trusted hosts:

```
PS > Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "1.2.3.4"                                          
Set-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'WSMan' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "1.2.3 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (WSMan:String) [Set-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand
```

If I ignore this message and try to connect, I get an error:

```
PS > Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "1.2.3.4" -Credential joe -Authentication Basic -Verbose -Port 5985
Windows PowerShell credential request
Enter your credentials.
Password for user joe: **************

Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server 1.2.3.4 failed with the following error message : Authentication Failure For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "1.2.3.4" -Credential joe -Aut ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (1.2.3.4:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

All I've seen about adding the WSMan provider is that I need to run `Enable-PSRemoting`, which doesn't exist on my Linux PowerShell, and also seems to be meant for the remote computer (and Nano Server has it enabled by default).

Comment: `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "1.2.3.4" -Credential 1.2.3.4\joe …`?  And the `WSMan` provider is well-satisfied accessible merely in an _elevated_ Windows PowerShell session.

Comment: @JosefZ I have it working now between two Windows computers, but I still can't connect to Windows from Linux. If I set TrustedHosts to "" on the Windows client, I get the same error as I'm getting on the Linux client. So I think the problem with Linux -> Windows is that I'm unable to set TrustedHosts (on the Linux client). I'm running PowerShell as root on Linux, but I still don't know how to get the WSMan provider there.

Comment: Did you have any chance to fix that?